# Passing instance during composition

Tags: python

I have a `Common` (or could call `Base`) class.

```
from enum import Enum
class Common:
  def a(self, condition):
    if condition == True:
      return self.Keys.F.value
    else:
      return self.Keys.G.value
  def b(self):
      return Common.a(self, True) * 10
```

and multiple other classes, all of them use the `Common` class.

```
class KlassOne:
  class Keys(Enum):
    E = 0
    F = 1
    G = 2
  def func(self, attribute):
    w = Common.a(self, condition=bool(attribute))
    x = Common.b(self)
    return w, x
```

```
class KlassTwo:
  class Keys(Enum):
    E = 0
    G = 1
    F = 2
  def func(self, attribute):
    y = Common.a(self, condition=bool(attribute))
    z = Common.b(self)
    return y, z
```

how do I avoid the `Common.a(self, ...)` way of implementing this.
Is there an alternative to it?

Comment: What is wrong with the `Common.a(self,...)` way?

Comment: "Is there an alternative to it?" - inheritance, I guess? `class KlassTwo(Common): def func(self): self.a()`. Or do you specifically _not_ want to use inheritance?

Comment: no, I would like to prefer composition over inheritance.

Comment: But `a` is just a function. Why does it need to be a method?

Comment: @quamrana changed it slightly

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate your class :

```
class KlassOne:
  def func(self, attribute):
    common = Common()
    w = common.a(condition=bool(attribute))
    x = common.b()
    return w, x
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the `Common.a(...` is not necessary inside `Common`:

```py
class Common:
  def a(self, condition):
    if condition == True:
      return 1
    else:
      return 2
  def b(self):
      return self.a(True) * 10
```

Second, if you want to pass `self` of `KlassOne` to a method of class `Common`, then `KlassOne` actually should be an instance of class `Common`:

```py
class KlassOne:
  def func(self, attribute):
    w = Common.a(self, condition=bool(attribute))  # <- here self is instance of KlassOne
    x = Common.b(self)
    return w, x
```

This is an argument strongly in favour of inheritance:

```
class KlassOne(Common):
  def func(self, attribute):
    w = self.a(condition=bool(attribute))
    x = self.b()
    return w, x
```

If you want to use composition, you would need to instantiate `Common`, e.g. like

```
class KlassOne:
  def __init__(self):
    self.common = Common()

  def func(self, attribute):
    w = self.common.a(condition=bool(attribute))
    x = self.common.b()
    return w, x
```

Answer (score 0):

Your recent update to the question means that `Common` looks more like a `mixin`. (I would refactor `b` like this)

```py
class Common:
  def a(self, condition):
    if condition == True:
      return self.Keys.F.value
    else:
      return self.Keys.G.value
  def b(self):
      return self.a(True) * 10
```

The above `Common` does not need to import from `enum`.

Now your other classes can inherit from the above, just as a mixin:

```py
from enum import Enum

class KlassOne(Common):
  class Keys(Enum):
    E = 0
    F = 1
    G = 2
  def func(self, attribute):
    w = self.a(condition=bool(attribute))
    x = self.b()
    return w, x
```